# How to deploy Play! app to GAE from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, playframework, gae-eclipse-plugin

Currently I deploy using command line:

`play war myappname -o myappname-war`

`APPENGINE_SDK_DIR/bin/appcfg update myappname-war/`

I am developing in Eclipse. Can I deploy the Play! app using Eclipse plugin as I used to for standard GAE apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the project name in Project Explorer, you should see a 'Google' menu option, go on that and select Deploy to App Engine. You will have to add your app engine login info there.

Comment: When i did that, it says it is not an App Engine project. I can't press the Deploy button.

Comment: rt click on the project name... go to properties > google> appengine and select use app engine (it should be checked already if its an app engine project)

Comment: i created a play! project, and eclipsify to open in eclipse, so there project structure is different.

Comment: But does eclipse recognize it as a GAE project like i showed in the previous comment? Does it give you any errors when you make it a GAE project

Comment: Yes I can turn it into a GAE project, but there are errors initially. To fix, firstly, I need to create a appengine-web.xml and put in /war/WEB-INF/lib. Secondly, eclipse somehow didn't recognize Properties > Google > Application > War directory, so I had to disable and enable. I can now upload deploy.. but i am running into a server error (thats another problem). THanks!

Comment: Anytime. The best is to create a web app project in eclipse itself and select it as a GAE. All the configurations get done for you.

Comment: @Jai How to create a web app project in eclipse? On the Play! website it says create a new project and eclipsify it with `play ec` and then import it to eclipse

Comment: @bizso09 you need the gwt plugin for eclipse to directly create web apps in eclipse. Once you install it, you will see a create new google  web app option directly in eclipse's create new project place. Are you having some other issues?

Comment: @Jai how do I turn the google web app into a Play! project and where does the play gae module come in?

Comment: @samwize I'm also running into server errors. How did you manage to fix those?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, all you need is to install the GAE plugin and deploy it as you would with any non-play application